# Ubuntu 12.04 does not start

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot

Im using Lenovo G580. I installed Win7 first, two months ago. Now, i want to install Ubuntu 12.04.
I used usb for installation. It went very well, but when i was reboot laptop after installation, it started Win7 not Ubuntu or bootloader for choice.
LiveUbuntu is working very well.

I tried install ubuntu a couple of times from other .iso.
I tried recover Grub.
When i change "boot" flag in gparted to partition with Ubuntu, BIOS show me error "missing operating system".("boot" flag is optionally on Windows partition c:/).

Can it be hardware mistake? Or i did some mistakes?

Comment: Are you using UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

Load Ubuntu using boot options (by hitting F12 immediately after clicking power button during start)
(In those boot options you will find ubuntu.)
After loading ubuntu ,
goto terminal and install boot-repair using,

> ~/sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>
> ~/sudo apt-get update
>
> ~/sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

In boot-repair window click "advanced options"

In Main options set Default OS as windows / ubuntu (my case its ubuntu)

In other options make sure the "repair windows boot files" options is set.

click "Apply" and Reboot

You will have a Grub boot menu with both ubuntu and windows in it

Hope it helped!
Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your LiveUSB is working fine, you can also reach Ubuntu Terminal by

1. loading Ubuntu in LiveUSB
2. click Try Ubuntu
3. once Ubuntu loads, open a Terminal and continue with commands mentioned by @Raja.